# Layout with Scrollview and drawerlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-scrollview

i have a activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/sfondomain" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
    </ListView>
```

but when i run my app, it crash:

Logcat: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9699157/

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.hide();

}
```

If I remove the ScrollView, my layout work fine...
I want put the ScrollView for landscape mode
Thank you.. sorry for my english!

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ... <ScrollView> ...<FrameLayout>... <ListView> crash!"ScrollView can host only one on direct child"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this it will work.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/sfondomain" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
    </ListView>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where does `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ...>` ends??

Comment: where does the ScrollView ends ?

Comment: How about a full example?

Comment: please specify where does the scroll view end.

Answer (score 2):

I also did the same but when 
i used linear layout as outer layer, it worked for me.
Means put your scrollview inside a linear layout.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @Hunt

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (tried with sdk 25), no need for LinearLayout, simply put the ScrollView inside the DrawerLayout and make sure the layout parts for the drawer come after the scrollView (otherwise clicking on an item in the drawer list will close the drawer just as if you clicked outside the list in the drawer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.MyApp.MyActivity">


<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/backButtonString"
android:id="@+id/button"
android:textColor="#ffffffff"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:onClick="tilbageClicked"
android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:textAllCaps="false"
/>



<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/myTextViewString"
android:id="@+id/myTextView"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:layout_below="@id/button"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

    <!-- content view -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/theContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/theDrawer"
    android:layout_gravity="start">




    <!-- List of items in drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/theList"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put ScrollView inside the DrawerLayout

if you're using an AppBarLayout can add `android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"`
or the height of your AppBarLayout